# Извлечение из файла, запись в файл

Tags: c++, сериализация

Добрый день, у меня есть структура

```
struct bird{   
    string name;  
    string type;   
    string habitat;   
    bool migrant;

    bird *next;   
};
```

мне нужно ее записать в файл, а потом извлечь. Пишу так(запись):

```
bird bTemp;   
ofstream output_file("Bird", ios::trunc);  
else {  
    while(fTemp != NULL) {   
        output_file.write((char*)&bTemp, sizeof(bird));   
         }  
    }
```

Извлечение

```
void ReadListFromFile() {   
    bird bTemp;  
    ifstream input_file("Bird");  
    if (!input_file.fail()) {  
        input_file.read((char*)&bTemp, sizeof(bird));  
    }  
}
```

В итоге создается двоичный файл, но при попытке чтения возникает ошибка сегментации

Comment: Прошу прощения за формат текста, еще только постигаю основы местного редактора

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чего вы, собственно, ожидали получить? У вас ведь экземпляры классов *string* да ещё указатель next.. как вы себе представляете чтобы такое работало? Вы мыслите номинально.. но вы должны думать о тех байтах, что вы туда пишете и о тех байтах, что читаете и пытаетесь потом использовать так будто они всегда были в памяти.

Comment: собственно да, не учел, ладно, сделаю по-другому

Answer (score 1):

советую вам быть более внимательным, так как во втором после очень точно подметили что вы пытаетесь работать с записными данными так как будто они всегда в памяти. Тоесть вам для начала нужно изменить структура данных на:

```
    struct bird{   
        string name;  
        string type;   
        string habitat;   
        bool migrant;
    };

+
    struct BIRD{
      bird label;
      bird *next;   
    };
```

Вы в файл должны записывать данные а не ссылки на них (bird *next).
то есть переходя по ссылке вы записываете только данные структуры (bird label), А когда будете их считывать то используя цикл будете заново собирать их в структуру (struct BIRD).
Думаю что поступив так, у вас не возник не проблем с записью данных не с их извлечением!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я заметил, приведение типов должно выглядеть так:

```
input_file.read((char *)&bTemp, sizeof(bird));
```

Да собственно и в первом случае тоже:

```
output_file.write((char *)&bTemp, sizeof(bird));
```

Потому как приводим не к типу char, а к указателю на char, которые необходимы методам write и read.

Comment: Все тоже самое, при попытке вывести - ошибка сегментации, в отладчике видно что в bTemp ничего не пишется

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{

   struct sss

   {

           char fam[20];

           int oklad;

   } s1;

   FILE *f1;

   // запись в файл

   f1 = fopen("1.bin","wb");

   while (true)

   {        

           puts(rus("Введите фамилию или 0 (конец ввода)"));

           scanf("%s",&s1.fam);

           if (note.fam[0] == '0') break;

           puts(rus("Введите оклад"));

           scanf("%d",&s1.oklad);

           fwrite(&s1,sizeof(s1),1,f1);

   }

   fclose(f1);

   puts(rus("Файл 1.bin записан\n"));

   //        чтение из файла

   f1 = fopen("1.bin","r+b");

   while(true)

   {

           fread(&s1,sizeof(s1),1,f1);

           if(!feof(f1)) break;

           printf("fam = %s, oklad = %d",s1.fam,s1.oklad);

   }

   fclose(f1);
```

Comment: ну вот так ты сваю сделай все будет норм.

Comment: Sema, спасибо конечно, но я хотел сделать именно через ifstream, ofstream. Но как правильно заметил cy6erGn0m нужно следить за тем что пишешь в файл. Пришлось немного изменить прогу и все зароботало. В любом случае спасибо за пример